# Calling a view function from render function

Tags: backbone.js

I'm writing a backbone.js application and wonder how to call a view function:

```
directory.GroupsListView = Backbone.View.extend({

    render:function () {

        Mousetrap.bind(['mod+s'], function(e) {
            self.group_save(e);
        });

        [... some render functions ...]

    },

    events: {
        "submit":               "group_save",
    },

    group_save: function() {
        alert('jeah!');
    }
});
```

What am I doing wrong? Or where did i have to put the Mousetrap binding?

Comment: `Mousetrap,bind(['mod+s'], group_save);` doesn't work?

Comment: No: Uncaught ReferenceError: group_save is not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a `var self = this` anywhere so presumably your `self` is [`window.self`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.self) and that's not what you want.

You have various options:

1. Grab `this` in a variable:

   ```
   var _this = this; // Don't use `self` for the reasons noted above
   Mousetrap.bind(['mod+s'], function(e) {
       _this.group_save(e);
   });
   ```
2. Use a bound function:

   ```
   Mousetrap.bind(['mod+s'], _(this.group_save).bind(this));
   ```

   You can also use [`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) or [`Function.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) (or some other library's version of function binding) if you prefer those over [`_.bind`](http://underscorejs.org/#bind).
3. Bind `group_save` per-instance:

   ```
   initialize: function() {
       _.bindAll(this, 'group_save');
   },
   render: function() {
       Mousetrap.bind(['mod+s'], this.group_save);
       //...
   ```

I don't know anything about Mousetrap but it might allow you to specify a `this` (possibly referred to as *context*) when you call `bind`, the common pattern would be `Mousetrap.bind(..., fn, this)` but Mousetrap might not support such things.

Also, don't forget to unbind your Mousetrap stuff when you remove your view.